# Import Time-Dependent Raster Pyramid into Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wmts

I have a set of geotiffs (think Landsat for example). I want to create a tile server that shows landsat's footprint overtime. How do I import these geotiffs, so as to create a **time dependent** WMTS with geoserver? Ideally, I would like to make a WMTS similar to https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/GIBS+API+for+Developers .

Comment: Do you really need a  tile server to show a footprint.  For footprints, I think vector, not tiles (for which I think raster).

Comment: When you say import , what do you mean, import into a geodatabase?

Comment: I think it does need to be a tile server. When I say, the footprint, I should have said, show the image itself. And as the user zooms in and out, the resolution of the raster changes appropriately to their zoom level.

By "import" I mean, that I want geoserver to turn a pyramid directory of tiles into a time-enabled WMTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) on how to create an image mosaic time series and then serve it via the GeoServer WMTS end point. If you have a very large number of files (>1000) then you may need a [pyramid store](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) but the set up is similar.

Comment: Ian, thanks so much for the reply. I went through the image mosiac time series tutorial, but I think it was what I needed. I also went through the pyramid store tutorial, but I didn't see a way to add time to the pyramid store. I think I need a pyramid approach because of the need to zoom in and out and load tiles at higher or lower resolution as appropriate. How would I add time to the pyramid store?

Comment: Try the mosaic first, it's easier. You need to add time to the pyramid index by hand if you go with that route.

Comment: When you say "by hand" do you mean manually creating a time column in the geoserver database?

Comment: Yes that is it exactly